# Looping through a result proxy object

Tags: python, for-loop, sqlalchemy

Got a nested loop with the inside loop being an sqlalchemy result proxy object. The problem I have is that when the second iteration of the outer loop is instantiated and goes back to iterating the resultproxy object, the script exists with the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object is closed.
```

Here is my code. The inside loop fails when X is > 0:

```
tbl = Table('users', self.meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=Engine)
stmt = select([tbl.c.id, tbl.c.name])
result = self.CONN.execute(stmt)
for x in range(2):
    for row in result:
        print(row[tbl.c.id])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exhausting the connection in the first inner loop itself. Try to make a copy and store it in a list:

```
tbl = Table('users', self.meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=Engine)
stmt = select([tbl.c.id, tbl.c.name])
result = self.CONN.execute(stmt)
ids = [row[tbl.c.id] for row in result]
for x in range(2):
    for i in ids:
        print(i)
```

Comment: But why? assuming instead of a result proxy object I had `for y in range(5)` as my internal loop, I'd expect it to iterate all the time without error. Why is the result proxy object different? is the result proxy object maintaining a connection to the database such that it will exhaust after 1 iteration? I don't get it.

Comment: `result` is a proxy to a database cursor that points to a row in the result. At the end of the inner loop, it points after the last row. So to go back, you need to reset that cursor back to the first row.